# Set initial state with multiple async calls in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I'm developing an app with React and Redux and I end up with a design doubt. The point is when I start the app I need to populate the store with several API request (I'm using fetch and redux-thunk) that returns some constants. This constants will be used by several components, and I can't attach them to a particular component since maybe the user is not loading it and goes directly to the another component that doesn't fetch the data....so... what's the best way to handle this?. How is the best way to populate and "initialState" in Redux? 
Also, is possible with fetch API handle multiple request as we do with $q all for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root component you could make the API calls in *componentDidMount* lifecycle method, populating the state with the returned values. State will be shared across all your app's components.

If the component you wish to make the call is a stateless functional component (and therefore doesn't have the lifecycle methods) you can wrap it as shown here:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-fetching-data-on-route-change

(The rest of that course covers async calls and using thunks - a must watch!)